# python nltk returning odd result for wordnet similarity measure

Tags: python, nltk, wordnet

I am trying to find similarity between two words using wordnet of python nltk. Two sample keyword is 'game' and 'leonardo'. First I have extracted all synsets of this two words and cross-matching each synset to find their similarity. Here is my code

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn

xx = wn.synsets("game")
yy = wn.synsets("leonardo")
for x in xx:
    for y in yy:
        print x.name
        print x.definition
        print y.name
        print y.definition
        print x.wup_similarity(y)
        print '\n'
```

Here is the total output:

> game.n.01 a contest with rules to determine a winner leonardo.n.01
> Italian painter and sculptor and engineer and scientist and architect;
> the most versatile genius of the Italian Renaissance (1452-1519)
> 0.285714285714
>
> game.n.02 a single play of a sport or other contest leonardo.n.01
> Italian painter and sculptor and engineer and scientist and architect;
> the most versatile genius of the Italian Renaissance (1452-1519)
> 0.285714285714
>
> game.n.03 an amusement or pastime leonardo.n.01 Italian painter and
> sculptor and engineer and scientist and architect; the most versatile
> genius of the Italian Renaissance (1452-1519)
> 0.25
>
> game.n.04 animal hunted for food or sport leonardo.n.01 Italian
> painter and sculptor and engineer and scientist and architect; the
> most versatile genius of the Italian Renaissance (1452-1519)
> 0.923076923077
>
> game.n.05 (tennis) a division of play during which one player serves
> leonardo.n.01 Italian painter and sculptor and engineer and scientist
> and architect; the most versatile genius of the Italian Renaissance
> (1452-1519)
> 0.222222222222
>
> game.n.06 (games) the score at a particular point or the score needed
> to win leonardo.n.01 Italian painter and sculptor and engineer and
> scientist and architect; the most versatile genius of the Italian
> Renaissance (1452-1519)
> 0.285714285714
>
> game.n.07 the flesh of wild animals that is used for food
> leonardo.n.01 Italian painter and sculptor and engineer and scientist
> and architect; the most versatile genius of the Italian Renaissance
> (1452-1519)
> 0.5
>
> plot.n.01 a secret scheme to do something (especially something
> underhand or illegal) leonardo.n.01 Italian painter and sculptor and
> engineer and scientist and architect; the most versatile genius of the
> Italian Renaissance (1452-1519)
> 0.2
>
> game.n.09 the game equipment needed in order to play a particular game
> leonardo.n.01 Italian painter and sculptor and engineer and scientist
> and architect; the most versatile genius of the Italian Renaissance
> (1452-1519)
> 0.666666666667
>
> game.n.10 your occupation or line of work leonardo.n.01 Italian
> painter and sculptor and engineer and scientist and architect; the
> most versatile genius of the Italian Renaissance (1452-1519)
> 0.25
>
> game.n.11 frivolous or trifling behavior leonardo.n.01 Italian painter
> and sculptor and engineer and scientist and architect; the most
> versatile genius of the Italian Renaissance (1452-1519)
> 0.222222222222
>
> bet_on.v.01 place a bet on leonardo.n.01 Italian painter and sculptor
> and engineer and scientist and architect; the most versatile genius of
> the Italian Renaissance (1452-1519)
> -1
>
> crippled.s.01 disabled in the feet or legs leonardo.n.01 Italian
> painter and sculptor and engineer and scientist and architect; the
> most versatile genius of the Italian Renaissance (1452-1519)
> -1
>
> game.s.02 willing to face danger leonardo.n.01 Italian painter and
> sculptor and engineer and scientist and architect; the most versatile
> genius of the Italian Renaissance (1452-1519)
> -1

But the similarity between game.n.04 and leonardo.n.01 is really odd. I think the similarity (0.923076923077) should not be so high.

> game.n.04
>
> animal hunted for food or sport
>
> leonardo.n.01
>
> Italian painter and sculptor and engineer and scientist and architect; the most versatile genius of the Italian Renaissance (1452-1519)
>
> 0.923076923077

Is there any problem with my concept?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [the docs](http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/howto/wordnet.html), the `wup_similarity()` method returns...

> ...a score denoting how similar two word senses are, based on the
>   depth of the two senses in the taxonomy and that of their Least Common
>   Subsumer (most specific ancestor node).

...and...

```
>>> from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
>>> game = wn.synset('game.n.04')
>>> leonardo = wn.synset('leonardo.n.01')
>>> game.lowest_common_hypernyms(leonardo)
[Synset('organism.n.01')]
>>> organism = game.lowest_common_hypernyms(leonardo)[0]
>>> game.shortest_path_distance(organism)
2
>>> leonardo.shortest_path_distance(organism)
3
```

...which is why it thinks they're similar, although I get...

```
>>> game.wup_similarity(leonardo)
0.7058823529411765
```

...which is different for some reason.

---

**Update**

> I want some measurement which will show that dissimilarity('game',
>   'chess') is much much less than dissimilarity('game', 'leonardo')

How about something like this...

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
from itertools import product

def compare(word1, word2):
    ss1 = wn.synsets(word1)
    ss2 = wn.synsets(word2)
    return max(s1.path_similarity(s2) for (s1, s2) in product(ss1, ss2))

for word1, word2 in (('game', 'leonardo'), ('game', 'chess')):
    print "Path similarity of %-10s and %-10s is %.2f" % (word1,
                                                          word2,
                                                          compare(word1, word2))
```

...which prints...

```
Path similarity of game       and leonardo   is 0.17
Path similarity of game       and chess      is 0.25
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. But what calculation will show their original/approximate dissimilarity?

Comment: @QuaziMarufurRahman Depends on how you define "dissimilarity". You might get better results with the `path_distance()` method, but it depends on what exactly you're trying to measure.

Comment: Actually I want some measurement which will show that dissimilarity('game', 'chess') is much much less than dissimilarity('game', 'leonardo')

Comment: Thanks for the updated code. Is it possible to visualize the relationship of two words? similarity between 'chess.n.02' and 'king.n.10' is 0.08. Visualization would help to verify this.

Comment: @QuaziMarufurRahman I couldn't find an easy way to do this, but it ought to be possible. Do a `dir()` on one of the synset objects, and try experimenting with its methods, like `hypernym_paths()` and `hypernym_distances()`.